# Calculate the end day of a week with DATE_TRUNC in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Is there a way to change the showing date to the end of each week instead of the beginning of the week.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', day + '1 day'::interval)::date - '1 day'::interval  AS anchor, AVG(value) AS average
FROM daily_metrics
WHERE metric = 'daily-active-users'
GROUP BY anchor
ORDER BY anchor
```

And the result is as below:
[image]

What I want to achieve is to make it 2018-03-03 (the end of the self defined week) instead of 2018-02-25 (the beginning of the self defined week), 2018-03-10 instead of 2018-03-04...

Answer (score 1):

Your trick with shifting back and forth by one day works just fine to get the start of your custom week. You get the end or your custom week (Saturday) by adding *5* instead of subtracting *1*:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', day + interval '1 day')::date + 5 AS anchor ...
```

Adding an `integer` to the `date`, signifying days.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL custom week number - first week containing Feb 1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092279/postgresql-custom-week-number-first-week-containing-feb-1st/41373012#41373012)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', day::DATE + 1)::date + 5 AS anchor, AVG(value) AS average
FROM daily_metrics
WHERE metric = 'daily-active-users'
GROUP BY anchor
ORDER BY anchor
```

When a date is the start date of a week adding 6 (1 + 5) days will move the date to the last date of the week. The the addition of one is to move sundays to the following week and the 5 to get the end of the week from the start date.

Note, PostgreSQL allows the addition of integers (= days) to dates.

Comment: but this way it wont be using my self defined weeks which is Sunday as the first day  and Saturday as the last day of the week

Comment: the date shown is correct but the calculation is not

Comment: Sorry, you‘re right. I forgot to adapt my description.