# Make date_trunc() start on Sunday instead of Monday

Tags: postgresql, datetime, amazon-athena, dbeaver

```
Select date_trunc('week',dateTime) Date_week, Max(Ranking) Runing_Total_ID
    from (select datetime, id , dense_rank () over (order by datetime) as Ranking
          from Table1)
 group by 1
```

This query is working for me to give me the running total of total IDs by week. But the week starts on Monday in Postgres by default. Is there any way to change the week start to SUNDAY?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sub>It's unclear how counting distinct dates translates to *"the running total of total IDs by week"*. But let's focus on the core question in the title.</sub>

#### Postgres 14 or newer

Use [**`date_bin()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN):

```sql
-- date_bin() in Postgres 14+
SELECT date_bin('7 days'              -- stride
              , datetime              -- source
              , timestamp '2023-1-1'  -- origin
               ) AS date_week
     , max(ranking) AS runing_total_id
FROM  (SELECT datetime, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS ranking FROM tbl) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z4WxfLLg)

The "origin" (`timestamp '2023-1-1'`) must be a Sunday in this case! It's also a valid `timestamp` literal. Don't mix `timestamp` & `timestamptz` to avoid corner-case errors.
See:

- [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299342/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-truncate-timestamps-to-5-minutes-in-postgres/75160734#75160734)
- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

#### Postgres 13 or older

Shift the timestamp back and forth. Add a day before feeding the `timestamp` to [**`date_trunc()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), then subtract again:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('week', datetime + interval '1 day') - interval '1 day' AS date_week
     , max(rnk) AS runing_total_id
FROM  (SELECT datetime, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS rnk FROM tbl) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/763xoiZC)

See:

- [PostgreSQL custom week number - first week containing Feb 1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092279/postgresql-custom-week-number-first-week-containing-feb-1st/41373012#41373012)

Comment: worked after using    '1' day   instead of '1 day'

Comment: Works as is in Postgres, trust me. Or don't, and try it.

Comment: Strange! I tried it as it is didn't work but then I changed it to    '1' day    it worked. I am working on Amazon Athena, Dbeaver.

Comment: @Ethan: Amazon Athena is not Postgres (at all!). Athena only accepts standard SQL (or so it claims). Postgres allows more reasonable [input syntax for intervals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) like the above, too. Hardcore SQL standard syntax would be `interval '1 0:00:00'` or `interval '1 0:0'` for "1 day".

Comment: Oh! I think it is presto.