# How to count records before current record date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
-----------------
id | date
-----------------
1  | 2023-10-07
2  | 2023-10-08
3  | 2023-10-14
```

and I want to get the record count up to the current record where the date is less than Sunday of the current record. So I want the output to look like this:

```
---------------------
week_number | count
---------------------
2           | 2
3           | 3
```

I tried different approaches, but the result is a counter for entries within the week. It’s as if he doesn’t look at all records before the current one, but only at those that are in the same week.

```
WITH weekly AS (
    SELECT
        get_week_number(date::DATE) AS week_number,
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM
        inventory
    WHERE
        date <= date_trunc('week', date)::date + INTERVAL '6 days'
    GROUP BY
        week_number
)

SELECT
    week_number, count
FROM
    inventory
        JOIN weekly ON get_week_number(date::DATE) = weekly.week_number
WHERE
    date <= date_trunc('week', date)::date + INTERVAL '6 days'
GROUP BY
    week_number, count
ORDER BY
    week_number;
```

Comment: Hi - can you explain what you mean by “Sunday of the current record”?

Comment: Your displayed result contradicts the description *"the record count up to the current record where the date is less than Sunday of the current record"*, which would require return one row for every input row. The count does not add up, either. Please clarify your question. Add a table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statement with exact data types and constraints), your version of Postgres, and, Ideally, a fiddle to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This computes

> the record count up to the current record where the date is less than Sunday of the current record

```sql
SELECT *
     , extract(week FROM date + 1) AS week_nr  -- fix off-by-1
     , count(*) OVER (ORDER BY date_bin('7 days', date, timestamp '2023-1-1')
                      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND '1 day' PRECEDING) AS count_til_last_week
FROM   inventory;
```

I assume by *"Sunday of the current record"* you mean weeks starting on Sunday. ISO weeks start on Monday. `date_trunc()` truncates weeks accordingly. Use `date_bin()` to "truncate" to Sunday. See:

- [Make date_trunc() start on Sunday instead of Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384627/make-date-trunc-start-on-sunday-instead-of-monday/69385327#69385327)

Add a day to your date before extracting the week number to fix the same off-by-1 error. (There may be corner-case issues around the turn of the year.)

To get the count of rows with a *"date is less than Sunday of the current record"*, you have to stop the count at "last week". `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND '1 day' PRECEDING` achieves that, after reducing every date to the Sunday of the week.
Details in [the manual about window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

To **aggregate** per week:

```sql
SELECT extract(year FROM sun) AS year
     , extract(week FROM sun + interval '1 day') AS week_number
     , sum(row_count) OVER (ORDER BY sun
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS count_til_last_week
FROM  (
   SELECT date_bin('7 days', date, timestamp '2023-1-1') AS sun
        , count(*) AS row_count
   FROM   inventory
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

Note that a week number without year results in confusing or wrong aggregations quickly. So I based counts on full dates and display the  year additionally. (No off-by-1 there.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/335SQrwL)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-U9jBnRK)

```
select id, 
       date, 
       extract(week from date) AS week_number,
       count(*)over(order by date) AS count
from inventory order by id;
```

| id | date | week_number | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-07 | 40 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-10-08 | 40 | 2 |
| 3 | 2023-10-14 | 41 | 3 |

```
select week_number, 
       sum(count)over(order by week_number) 
from( select extract(week from date::DATE) AS week_number,
             count(*) AS count
       from inventory
       group by week_number) AS subquery;
```

| week_number | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 2 |
| 41 | 3 |

Default window [frame clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, meaning  `count()over()` is going to *get the record count up to the current record* the way you wanted.